# Keyword arguments for function wrapped with decorator not working

Tags: python

All the tutorials I find on decorators suggest using `*args, **kwargs` in the wrapping function's signature, to handle arguments from the wrapped function.  Yet kwargs are not working, while plain args are:

```
from functools import wraps


def wrapper(a_thing):
    @wraps(a_thing)
    def do_thing(*args, **kwargs):
        print('before')
        print(kwargs)
        value = a_thing(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after", *args, **kwargs)
        return value
    return do_thing


@wrapper
def output(*args, **kwargs):
    print('during', *args, **kwargs)

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Here's my interactive output:

```
(Pdb) output(99, 100)
before
{}
during 99 100
after 99 100
(Pdb) output(arg1=99, arg2=100)
before
{'arg1': 99, 'arg2': 100}
*** TypeError: 'arg1' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
(Pdb)
```

Here's [an example](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/03/simple-python-decorator-examples/) of one of many such tutorials:

What's the point of using **kwargs if it doesn't work?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to unpack in the calls to `print`; `print` only accepts a limited number of keyword arguments, and will reject all others. Presumably you just want to see what was passed, so print the raw `tuple` and `dict` without unpacking:

```
def wrapper(a_thing):
    @wraps(a_thing)
    def do_thing(*args, **kwargs):
        print('before')
        print(kwargs)
        value = a_thing(*args, **kwargs)
        print("after", args, kwargs)  # Removed unpacking
        return value
    return do_thing


@wrapper
def output(*args, **kwargs):
    print('during', args, kwargs)  # Removed unpacking
```

The point of unpacking is that it passes the elements of a `*` unpacked iterable as sequential positional arguments, and the key value pairs from a `**` unpacked mapping using the keys as keyword arguments, and the values as the associated value. So when you did:

```
    print('during', *args, **kwargs)
```

having called into the function with `output(arg1=99, arg2=100)`, it was as if you ran:

```
    print('during', arg1=99, arg2=100)
```

Neither `arg1` nor `arg2` are keywords accepted by `print`, so it screamed at you. By removing the unpacking, the `print` becomes equivalent to:

```
    print('during', (), {'arg1': 99, 'arg2': 100})
```

which is perfectly valid (it's printing the `tuple` and `dict` directly, not trying to unpack).

Comment: Ahh, thank you, the "function" mentioned in the error is the `print()` function, not the `output` function like I assumed..... wow.